# Shorter way to write my if statement in php

Tags: php

Besides shortening the variable name, is there a shorter way to write this code. It hurts my eyes.

```
if($day > 30 && ($month == 1 || $month == 3 || $month == 5 || $month == 7 || $month == 8 || $month == 10 || $month == 12))
```

Comment: `in_array` or `index_of` should do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($day > cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year)) { 
# do your error handling here
}
```

You should always search for the [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

Comment: Ah best one so far. I saw that function but was unsure how to use it till now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of ways.

Easiest is to use an array and [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
$months = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12);
if($day > 30 && in_array($month, $months))
```

Comment: I would also suggest renaming the $months variable to something more akin to $monthsWith31Days to help clarify what its for.